# convert string yyyymmdd to date in duck db

Tags: sql, duckdb

Hi does anyone know how to convert a string in YYYYMMDD format to yyyy-mm-dd in duck db?

have tried to cast, have tried strptime(date, 'yyyymmdd'), have tried convert, to_date

Answer (score 1):

Duckdb has other literals for dates see [manual](https://duckdb.org/docs/sql/functions/dateformat.html)

```
SELECT strptime('19920302', '%Y%m%d');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so like this

```
SELECT strftime(DATE your_string, '%Y-%m-%d');
```

See [duckdb documentation](https://duckdb.org/docs/sql/functions/dateformat.html) for more information :)

You could also try converting the string first outside of duck db like so:

```
string.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

and then passing it to duck db.

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error with this:

`with a as (

    select *, cast(date as text) as string_date from raw_data
)

select * , strftime(date string_date, '%Y-%m-%d') from a `

ParserException: Parser Error: syntax error at or near "string_date"
LINE 6: select * , strftime(date string_date, '%Y-%m-%d') from a
                                 ^

Comment: It's like the error is between date and string and I don't understand why? Do you have any ideas? Data is definitely in yyyymmdd format